# What is the best UML diagram for explaining recursive tree traversal?

Tags: c#, parsing, tree, uml, diagram

I want to explain my C# code which traverses a parse tree for code analysis. It is similar to the following but longer:

```
    private void traverse(ParseTreeNode node)
    {
        if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (node.Term.Name.ToUpper())
        {
            case "FILE":
                traverse(node.ChildNodes[0]);
                return;

            case "PROGRAM":
                traverse(node.ChildNodes[0]);
                return;

            //etc.
        }
    }
```

What is the most appropriate UML diagram for showing this? Thanks

Comment: Why use UML? Seems like a simple block diagram would suffice there.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: http://docent.ehsal.be/docent/Smitslieven/isa/process/flow_Euclid.gif one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing the discussion arisen in the comments after dasblinkenlight's answer, I suggest the following activity diagram as a solution:

[image]

Activity diagram puts an emphasis on the sequence of steps in a process/algorithm, decisions made on the way, manipulated data and calculations, eventually concurrent tasks, invocations, etc.

There is always some kind of context to activity diagram. In this case it is a method traverse().

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explaining behavior of the tree traversal, not structure of the tree, your choices are limited to *Behavior Diagrams*. Since you wish to show what happens inside a method, your choices are further narrowed down to *Interaction Diagrams*.

At this point, you need to choose between a *Sequence Diagram* and a *Collaboration Diagram*. Both diagram types could be used to show a tree traversal. The main difference is in how the method calls are going to be shown. In the sequence diagram you would show invocations with horizontal lines going across the "swim lanes", while the collaboration diagram will distinguish the calls using numbers.

Since this is recursion, you would be showing multiple calls to the method with the same name. This gives advantage to sequence diagrams, because the readers would not need to check the numbering to see whose `traverse` method you are calling. That is why I would use a sequence diagram..

When I draw sequence diagrams showing recursive interaction, I build a small object graph on a piece of paper, and then draw out the interactions of the recursive method.

**EDIT :** Here is why I would *not* use an Activity Diagram <sup>*</sup> to show a sequence of recursive calls. Despite a note in the comment suggesting to use an Activity Diagram for this, I think this is not a good idea: activity diagrams are good at capturing algorithms happening within the same object, while here we deal with an algorithm that spawns multiple objects.

<sup>*</sup> Which is a glorified flowchart, a notoriously poor mechanism for capturing the essence of recursive algorithms.

Comment: I would not agree with this. Both Sequence and Collaborations are used to display CONCRETE scenario in terms of collaborating objects. In this case we don't have collaborating objects and we have a lot of if-then-else structures (decicions and branching). The best fitting diagram in this case is activity diagram. It puts emphasis on the algorhitmic flows, conditions, therefore covering all possible scenarios and passes through the method.

Comment: @Aleks What do you mean "we don't have collaborating objects"? We most certainly do have collaborating objects - the nodes of the tree. Moreover, there is very, very little branching going on here - in fact, the same method is being called over and over, with the dispatch being done on the node term name (more likely than not, this is a missed opportunity to inherit).

Comment: It's not about "little" or "lot of" branching. There is branching, we want to show it, and that's all. Note that this is only a fragment of the code, there is more. On the other side, "nodes" are NOT collaborating here, in terms of sending messages to each other (the focus of the sequence/collaboration diagram). Here the nodes are simply manipulated by the method (algorhitm) itself. Even recursive invocation is not very easy to show in sequence diagram, while in activity you have the reuseable action.

Comment: @Aleks There are different kinds of branching - branching that changes dynamically with passage of time (say, because a numeric condition changes) and branching that essentially repeats the structure of your object tree. This is not the branching that you want to show in a diagram as a branching, because it gives the reader an impression that the decision point on the branch is inside the algorithm being depicted in the diagram. However, this impression is misleading, because the actual choice has been made at the time of the tree construction; the algorithm simply tracks these decisions.

Comment: I must strongly disagree again. I don't see how the "branching type" impacts the choice we're discussing here. You said in the EDIT part that "algorithm spawns multiple objects". True, but as told before, these objects ARE NOT COLLABORATING with each other (sequence diagram focus) but rather are enclosed in a larger scope and so being manipulated "from outside" - this larger scope sets the limits of the activity diagram (in UML it is all about the right abstraction). Finally, I suggest that you simply draw a sequence diagram showing this algorihtm. I'll do the activities...